# Storage space "disappeared" on internal SSD of MacBook Air

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, partitioning, ssd

After letting the FreeBSD installer to "automatically create an EFI partition" on my MacBook Air, there seems to be some problem with my internal SSD:

```
192:~ sunqingyao$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                       0xEE                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            60.6 GB    disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:                       0xEE                         209.7 MB   disk0s4
```

Obviously, `209.7 MB + 60.6 GB + 650.0 MB + 209.7 MB < 121.3 GB`. Nearly 60GB of my disk space just disappears!

Also, in case it's relevant:

```
192:~ sunqingyao$ sudo gpt -r show disk0
Password:
gpt show: disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         MBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  118284248      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  118693888    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  119963424     409600      4  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
  120373024  104857600      5  GPT part - 516E7CB6-6ECF-11D6-8FF8-00022D09712B
  225230624   11747328      6  GPT part - 516E7CB5-6ECF-11D6-8FF8-00022D09712B
  236977952        190      7  GPT part - 83BD6B9D-7F41-11DC-BE0B-001560B84F0F
  236978142          1
  236978143         32         Sec GPT table
  236978175          1         Sec GPT header
```

First Aid of Disk Utility doesn't help:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FreeBSD installer appears to have created a very bad [hybrid MBR](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) on your disk, and this is confusing OS X. The `diskutil list` output is showing the MBR side of the hybrid MBR, and this output includes two type-0xEE (protective) partitions, which tends to confuse OS X. The `gpt -r show disk0` output, OTOH, shows seven GPT partitions and a "suspicious MBR," to use its term.

This can be fixed with my [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`)](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) tool:

1. Obtain `gdisk`. You can use the OS X version or boot a Linux emergency disk that includes `gdisk`. (An [Ubuntu installer](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) should work well.)
2. Launch `gdisk` on the disk, as in `sudo gdisk /dev/disk0` under OS X or (probably) `sudo gdisk /dev/sda` under Ubuntu.
3. Type `p` to view the partition table and be sure you're working on the correct disk.
4. Type `x` to enter the experts' menu.
5. Type `n` to create a new protective MBR to replace the bad hybrid MBR. Note that `gdisk` will simply display a new prompt; it won't verify that a new protective MBR has been created.
6. Type `p` to view the partition table again to be sure you haven't accidentally done something bad.
7. Type `w` to save your changes and exit. You'll be asked to verify this change.

At this point, the problem should be fixed; however, you may need to reboot before the OS will fully recognize the changes.

Note, however, that this procedure will render your Mac unable to boot BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode OSes. Depending on how you installed FreeBSD, you might need to install its EFI-mode boot loader. This is called `loader.efi`, but I'm not sure exactly where you'd find it or how you'd configure it, if it's not already installed. Perhaps [this FreeBSD wiki entry](https://wiki.freebsd.org/UEFI) would help, although it's scarce on practical end-user details. You might also want or need an EFI-mode boot manager, such as my [rEFInd,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) to select between the OSes.

Alternatively, instead of replacing the hybrid MBR with a protective MBR, you could use `gdisk` to create a saner protective MBR. You might then need to re-install FreeBSD's BIOS-mode boot loader, and perhaps install rEFInd to simplify booting between the OSes. Assuming FreeBSD can boot in EFI mode on your Mac, though, I recommend booting in this way rather than in BIOS mode, because hybrid MBRs are ugly and *dangerous* hacks. Far too many people have completely trashed their OSes and lost important data because of hybrid MBRs.

Comment: Thanks sir, you're a life saver! Currently my disk is fixed and FreeBSD is installed & bootable! Strangely however, [there are two EFI partitions on the disk now](https://superuser.com/q/1214527/554799), but this is a tinyyyyyyy problem compared with the one you just fixed with your expertise and your magical `gdisk`!

Comment: Having two ESPs isn't a problem, aside from the lost space.