# Cannot boot into FreeBSD after installation

Tags: boot, mac, uefi, freebsd, refind

I installed FreeBSD on my MacBook Air through a USB stick. During the installation, I'm asked to choose partition on which FreeBSD is installed. I created a `freebsd-ufs` partition and a `freebsd-swap` partition. Then the installer asked me whether I want to create an EFI partition to make the disk bootable:

[image: screenshot of a FreeBSD installer message window asking me whether to create an EFI partition]

Since I already have an EFI partition on my disk, and [I don't need two EFI partitions](https://superuser.com/questions/1214527/do-i-need-an-separate-efi-partition-for-each-os-sharing-a-common-disk), I chose No.

After the installation, I saw no boot options read "FreeBSD" in rEFInd's boot menu.

```
sunqingyaos-MacBook-Air:~ sunqingyao$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            60.6 GB    disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:               FreeBSD Swap                         6.2 GB     disk0s4
   5:                FreeBSD UFS                         53.5 GB    disk0s5
```

Also,

```
sunqingyaos-MacBook-Air:~ sunqingyao$ sudo gpt -r show disk0
Password:
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  118284248      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  118693888    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  119963424     409600
  120373024  104447992      5  GPT part - 516E7CB6-6ECF-11D6-8FF8-00022D09712B
  224821016   12156928      4  GPT part - 516E7CB5-6ECF-11D6-8FF8-00022D09712B
  236977944        199
  236978143         32         Sec GPT table
  236978175          1         Sec GPT header
```

I checked the EFI partition with `mountesp`, which comes with rEFInd, but didn't find anything like `freebsd.efi`. Is this the problem?

```
sunqingyaos-MacBook-Air:~ sunqingyao$ sudo mountesp
The ESP has been identified as /dev/disk0s1; attempting to mount it....
The ESP is mounted at /Volumes/ESP
sunqingyaos-MacBook-Air:~ sunqingyao$ ls -la /Volumes/ESP/EFI/refind/
total 641
drwxrwxrwx  1 sunqingyao  staff    1536 Jun  4 21:48 .
drwxrwxrwx  1 sunqingyao  staff     512 Jun  3 19:53 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 sunqingyao  staff    4096 May 27 19:18 ._icons
-rwxrwxrwx  1 sunqingyao  staff    4096 Jun  4 09:26 ._refind.conf
-rwxrwxrwx  1 sunqingyao  staff    4096 May 27 19:18 ._refind.conf-sample
-rwxrwxrwx  1 sunqingyao  staff    4096 May 27 19:18 ._refind_x64.efi
drwxrwxrwx  1 sunqingyao  staff    1536 May 27 19:18 drivers_x64
drwxrwxrwx@ 1 sunqingyao  staff   10752 May 27 19:18 icons
drwxrwxrwx  1 sunqingyao  staff   10752 Oct  9  2015 icons-backup
drwxrwxrwx  1 sunqingyao  staff    2560 May 27 19:18 keys
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 sunqingyao  staff   23155 Jun  4 09:26 refind.conf
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 sunqingyao  staff   27928 May 27 19:18 refind.conf-sample
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 sunqingyao  staff  231464 May 27 19:18 refind_x64.efi
drwxrwxrwx  1 sunqingyao  staff     512 Oct  9  2015 tools_x64
```

Answer (score 1):

The last I checked, FreeBSD installed its EFI boot loader using the fallback filename (`EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` on the ESP). rEFInd should locate that and offer to launch it as the "fallback boot loader." If you don't see it, perhaps you skipped a step during installation or selected an incorrect option; or maybe bypassing the option to create a new ESP confused the FreeBSD installer and caused the boot loader to not be installed. I'm not an expert on FreeBSD installation, though, so I'm afraid I can't be more specific.